# ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: Get http://172.17.166.5:5000/v2/: dial tcp 172.17.166.5:5000: getsockopt: connection refused?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

When I'm using my pipeline on GitLab, I have this error occurs on my screen, and I don't know what to do to solve this, I already tried to check my daemon.json but the IP adress "172.17.166.5:5000" is already set with 'insecure-registry'... I already tried to restart my docker and gitlab-runner but nothing changes.
And I don't know why the connection is refused.

There is what occurs :

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.5.0 (577f813d)
  on XF100X05 mhTM83d9
Using Docker executor with image 172.17.166.5:5000/papy37:latest ...
Pulling docker image 172.17.166.5:5000/papy37:latest ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: Get http://172.17.166.5:5000/v2/: dial tcp 172.17.166.5:5000: getsockopt: connection refused (executor_docker.go:188:0s)
```

thanks a lot !!

I already tried to restart the gitlab-runner and my docker services, check the daemon.json file